# cef3 tooltips are not displaying

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

I'm starting to learn CEF3 and am having a problem getting tooltips to appear over hyperlinks. I understand that I need to implement `cef_display_handler::onTooltip` for this to work, but I am not sure how to handle the implementation. Could someone show me how to get tooltips to display? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

From `cef_display_handler.h`:

```
// Called when the browser is about to display a tooltip. |text| containsthe

// text that will be displayed in the tooltip. To handle the display of the

// tooltip yourself return true. Otherwise, you can optionally modify |text|

// and then return false to allow the browser to display the tooltip.
///

/*--cef(optional_param=text)--*/

virtual bool OnTooltip(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                     CefString& text) { return false; }
```

I am stumped on how to implement this method. I have not created tooltips in C++ or CEF.

**Does anyone have a sample implementation that I could see, please?**

**Update**
I have upgraded to cef 3.2171.1979_windows32, and am still not seeing tooltips when I launch my browser from within my application. My application uses cef to display html report files, which have links to open database reports with custom urls. This is why I am not able to simply use cefclient. Is there something I am missing with the libcef_dll_wrapper to allow tooltips to display?

Comment: Can you edit your question to share the relevant parts of your code please?

Comment: I think this function only exists to let you override the alt text or default tooltip, unless as it says you are doing offscreen rendering in which case it can't display a tooltip window.  As a check I just ran the CefClient sample and it displays tooltips for alt-text for example without ever overriding this function.  I just realized that the comments for the version I am looking at add another two lines :  "// When window rendering is disabled the application is responsible for
  // drawing tooltips and the return value is ignored."  What version of CEF are you on?  I tested this on 2171